# Angular HttpClient post: error HttpErrorResponse

Tags: angular, typescript, http-post

So, when i try to make a POST request:

```
  sendData(data: {username: string, password: string, bdate: Date}){
    console.log(data)
    this.http.post('localhost:4200/register', data)
    .subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
```

Then it gives me an [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8v5W.png)

Comment: maybe `http://`?

Comment: It works with https:// thanks!

Comment: Oh, wait now to CORS gives me an error

Comment: Are you using a proxy..?

Comment: No, sorry for the late answer